# Case insensitive search expression linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, expression

I have a method to create Expression where I have code that handles search

Here is method

```
 private static Expression GenerateExpressionForString(Expression left, ItemComparisonOperator itemComparisonOperator,
    object value)
{
    StringComparisonOperator stringOperator = Enum.Parse<StringComparisonOperator>(itemComparisonOperator.ToString());
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(value, left.Type);

    if (stringOperator is StringComparisonOperator.Equal or StringComparisonOperator.NotEqual)
    {
        ExpressionType nativeComparison = Enum.Parse<ExpressionType>(stringOperator.ToString());
        return Expression.MakeBinary(nativeComparison, left, constant);
    }

    if (stringOperator is StringComparisonOperator.Contains)
    {
        return Expression.Call(left, stringOperator.ToString(), Type.EmptyTypes, constant); 
    }
    
    if (stringOperator is StringComparisonOperator.StartsWith
        or StringComparisonOperator.EndsWith)
        return Expression.Call(left, stringOperator.ToString(), Type.EmptyTypes, constant);

    throw new NotSupportedException($"Invalid comparison operator '{itemComparisonOperator}'.");
}
```

Now all working great instead of `Contains`

It searches value case sensitive.

Here is a data example that comes to this method

**Left parameter -**
[image]

**Comparison operator**

[image]

**value parameter**

[image]

How I can make it case-insensitive?

Comment: Probably better to use proper overload [string.Contains(string value, StringComparison comparisonType)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0#system-string-contains(system-string-system-stringcomparison))

Answer (score 0):

So I found solution

Here is it

```
 if (stringOperator is StringComparisonOperator.Contains)
    {
        var toLower = Expression.Call(left,
            typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
        return Expression.Call(toLower, stringOperator.ToString(), Type.EmptyTypes, constant); 
    }
```